# How to derive the Log and Exp functions of a Geometric Algebra Rotor for Spherical Interpolation (Slerp) in 4D

Tags: rotations, programming, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I am trying to create a Slerp function between two 4D Rotors

```
Rotor Slerp(Rotor a, Rotor b, t) { ... }
```

I have been told you can do an interpolation using Log and Exp functions to scale the bivector by the angle of rotation, scale it with t, and then turn the bivector back into the rotor.

```
Rotor difference = a.Reverse * b;
Rotor interpolatedRotor = a * Exp(t * Log(difference));
```

where Exp takes a 4D Bivector and returns a 4D Rotor, and Log takes a 4D Rotor and returns a 4D Bivector.

I was directed to [this notebook](https://enki.ws/ganja.js/examples/coffeeshop.html#NSELGA), but it is riddled with divide by zeros errors, sqrt of negatives and unclamped ASin functions leading to a bunch of NaN values, but on top of that I don't understand what it is the code is actually doing.
I tried to put logic in place to account for all the problems, but the Slerp does not actually do what it is supposed to do.

I could really use a hand helping me break down the Log and Exp functions with respect to the components of a Rotor and the components of a Bivector, and if it is something that is different for different dimensions, then answers that focus on 4D would be great.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you referring to a geometric algebra over a 4D space? What metric? The metric makes a significant difference here.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Yes in 4D space, not sure what you mean by the metric?

Comment: You can have a geometric algebra over Euclidean space with metric signature $(++++)$, or over Minkowski space $(+---)$, or something else like $(+++0)$ (the signature of PGA). "Signature" meaning what an orthonormal basis squares to, e.g. in the Minkowski case $$e_0^2=1,\quad e_1^2=e_2^2=e_3^2=-1.$$  The answer to your question depends on which metric you're interested in. If you're only interested in the Euclidean case then that should be easier than the general problem.

Comment: Also, I should note the comment at the very top of the file you link to directly cites a paper on this topic. The code also deals with several different metrics, so perhaps that is where your difficulty in using it is coming from? (I haven't really looked into it though, so I have no real opinion on whether or not the code is broken.)

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, I am not too familiar with it all. I am looking at GA over 4D Euclidean space. I was looking into 3.5 and 3.6 in the paper I linked

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff I don't suppose you are able to help with my question now we have established the problem space?